# winston and node version compatibilty

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using `winston v3.2.1` and `winston-daily-rotate-file v3.9.0` in my node application.
On windows my `node` and `npm` versions are `v10.15.3` and `v6.4.1` respectively. On linux I have `v8.10.0` and `v3.5.2` respectively.
On windows, `winston` is working fine but on linux, it is not.

What are the comptabile versions for `winston` libraries?

Comment: Define "not working". The version of `npm` should be largely irrelevant. The version of Node... likely the culprit.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have the 10.15 LTS version of node installed on Linux?

Comment: @crashmstr Server on which I have to deploy the application is running on v8.10.0 node and v3.5.2 npm. Cant change that.

Comment: @DaveNewton "not working" means the error() and info() statements are throwing error as undefined.

Comment: `"@types/node": "^10.12.19",` is in their package.json, so you would at least need to find an older version. Not sure how you would do that. If you knew in advance the node version of the server you were deploying to, I think it might have been better to use that same version instead of the current 10.15 LTS.

Comment: You'll likely need to downgrade your Winston version. Pro tip: don't test or run or anything on a Node version you're not deploying to--only bad things can happen.